# Can't install any packages with apt

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I have big problem on my Debian 6 server. I can't install/uninstall any packages on my system. When I try install something I see this error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 consolekit : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.24.2-1 is to be installed
              Breaks: udev (< 204-1) but 164-3 is to be installed
 libgudev-1.0-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.24.2-1 is to be installed
 libpolkit-agent-1-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.24.2-1 is to be installed
                       Depends: libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (>= 0.105) but 0.96-4+squeeze2 is to be installed
 libsecret-1-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.38.0) but 2.24.2-1 is to be installed
 libudisks2-0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.24.2-1 is to be installed
 policycoreutils : Depends: libaudit0 but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-input-all : Depends: xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: xserver-xorg-input-wacom but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev : Depends: libevdev2 (>= 0.9.1) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libmtdev1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics : Depends: libevdev2 (>= 1.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try `apt-get -f install`:

```
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of sysvinit-utils, which would be broken by installation of startpar ...
dpkg: no, sysvinit-utils is essential, will not deconfigure
 it in order to enable installation of startpar
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/startpar_0.59-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installing startpar would break existing software
configured to not write apport reports

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/startpar_0.59-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list` contains:

```
deb http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main
deb-src http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
deb http://debian.sur5r.net/i3/ squeeze universe
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian sid main
```

Comment: Try commenting out the last line (add `#` at the start of the line), the one containing `sid`; then `apt-get update` and try `apt-get -f install`.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors stem from the fact that your `apt` configuration mixes Squeeze (Debian 6) and Sid (Debian unstable). This is a bad idea...

You need to drop `sid` from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file (comment the line with `#`), then run

```
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
```

to fix things.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error:

```
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of sysvinit-utils, which would 
      be broken by installation of startpar ...
dpkg: no, sysvinit-utils is essential, will not deconfigure
      it in order to enable installation of startpar
dpkg: error processing archive 
   /var/cache/apt/archives/startpar_0.59-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
installing startpar would break existing software
```

This is how I fixed it:

```
dpkg --auto-deconfigure --force-remove-essential -i   \
             /var/cache/apt/archives/startpar_0.59-3_amd64.deb \
             /var/cache/apt/archives/sysvinit-utils_2.88dsf-59_amd64.deb
```

The upgrade I was doing then continued on fine.

Comment: This was very helpful for me when i updated an old NAS running Wheezy to Jessie today.

Answer (score 2):

Squeeze has been deprecated , You have to do :

```
sed -i 's/squeeze/wheezy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```